# Programmatically access virtual host site from IP (python/IIS)

Tags: python, iis

We have some servers that are within a load balancer that have multiple sites hosted on each one (one major one and two minor ones). Since they are in a load balancer, the actual domain they are accessed with points to the load balancer, not the individual servers.

What is a way to be able to programmatically access each site on each server? The servers are using IIS 8.5 with each site under a different virtual host binding. I am attempting to use the following Python code (with the popular [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library):

```
path = ""
site_ip = 1.2.3.4
header = {'host': 'www.sitedomainhere.com'}
r = requests.get('http://{0}/{1}'.format(site_ip, path))
```

But I am not getting the correct site. Am I just missing some IIS setting that allows you to do this? Or am I doing something wrong? Or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Typo. Dammit.

```
r = requests.get('http://{0}/{1}'.format(site_ip, path))
```

Should be

```
r = requests.get('http://{0}/{1}'.format(site_ip, path), headers=header)
```